# Правильная реализация одной таблицы для пользователей/гостей

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, есть вопрос по том, как правильно реализовать запись в БД некоторых данных.

Есть определенное действие, к пример -  комментарий. Комментарий может оставлять как и пользователь сайта, так и гость сайта. База данных имеет 2 таблицы `user` и `comment`.

Архитектура `comment`:

- id(тип integer, размер: 11, primary+auto-increment)
- user_id(integer, 11, index, есть связь с таблицей `user` по стоблцу `id`)
- comment(varchar, 256)
- date(integer, 11)

То есть, после добавления комментария от пользователя записывается его в `user_id`, но как отмечать гостей? На данный момент у меня есть 3 решения, правда не знаю какое будет верное, либо есть ли верное среди них:

1. Сделать дополнительный столбец `is_guest`, в `user_id` записывать `null`.
2. Просто записывать `null` в `user_id`.
3. Сделать пользовательский аккаунт, id которого будет "гостевым".
4. Отдельная таблица для гостевых комментариев(без `user_id`, и комментариев пользователей.

Так какой способ будет верным?

Comment: 2 или 3. в зависимости от того, надо ли выводить какую либо информацию кроме guest вместо имени для комментариев гостей. и не дать ли возможность позже зарегится что бы коменты стали твоими (например в пределах сессии)

Comment: Я бы делал так, создал некоторый диапазон аккаунтов - типа "гость" "оповещение" и т.д. и использовал их. То есть вариант 3. Что касается `NULL` - `NULL` это не данные, это их отсутсвие, поэтому использование `NULL`, ИМХО, антипатерн.

Answer (score 0):

Классическая проблема физического и юридического лица, в своих проектах я создаю 2 таблицы Users и Guests, в таблице Comments создаю следующие поля [id, comment, owner_id, table_name]. Добавляю 2 ForeignKey для каждой из таблиц.